# Delphi and XPath functions

Tags: delphi, xpath, msxml

Can I use Xpath node set function position() in Delphi's function selectNodes() to select only a certain number of element from a node list? If I do like this:

```
selectNodes('Item[1]')
```

its all fine and I get the element with index 1, but when I try

```
selectNodes('Item[position()<10]')
```

I get exception 'unknown method', when I try

```
selectNodes('Item[<10]')
```

I get 'unexpected token <'. 
Im using delphi7 and I also imported new type library into my project with newer versions of msxml.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Delphi question I think, but an MSXML one. Check the [MSXML docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(VS.85).aspx) or rather the [MS XPath docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(VS.85).aspx).

Hmm, according to the [XPath examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(VS.85).aspx) posted on MSDN "`Item[position() &lt; 10]`" should have worked, at least if "`Item`" is the name of the element you're after...

Comment: Those examples are about xslt.

Answer (score 0):

selectNodes requires a string, so you should try:

```
selectNodes('Item[position()<10]')
```

Or whatever xpath query.

Comment: That was my first impulse too at first but this would be a compile-time error and I don't think that's what the OP got. I think he just left out the quotes.

Comment: correct, im using string of course otherwise i would get errors on compiling. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a version-issue? I have imported typelibrary from MS XML 6, and gets no error.